# How do I export a Crystal Report to a Unicode text file?

Tags: unicode, vb6, crystal-reports, export, ansi

I'm trying to export a Crystal Report to a text file, while preserving any Unicode characters that are found within. By default, Crystal Reports seems to export to an ANSI text file.

Here is a highly simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
Dim objCRReport As CRAXDRT.Report
[...]
objCRReport.ExportOptions.FormatType = 8 'crEFTText
objCRReport.ExportOptions.DestinationType = 1 'crEDTDiskFile
objCRReport.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\reportInTextFormat.txt"
objCRReport.Export blnPromptUser
```

Since it creates a file in ANSI format, I lose any special characters that were found within the report. These characters are all fine when you view the Crystal Report directly.

Please note that I am referencing the "Crystal Reports 9 ActiveX Designer Runtime Library" specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to point out that I've tried pre-creating a Unicode file with the same name *prior* to the export, hoping the Crystal code would notice the file, and append to it rather than creating an ANSI file, but unfortunately this is not the case.

I then thought I could get around this problem (ninja style) by just exporting to an RTF file (which preserves the characters), then reading the contents of this RTF (minus the formating). I would then create a Unicode text file myself, writing the RTF contents to it. Unfortunately, to achieve this, I had to look into using a RichTextBox, but encountered a slew of problems with that. I think I'd have more success in VB.Net, but unfortunately I'm stuck with VB6 for this task.

After trying those approaches, I found [an article](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3874) that seems to suggest that Crystal Reports 9 *supports* exporting to a Unicode Text file, but I have yet to see it work. It mentions that the print engine supports it, so I'm going to look deeper to see if I can invoke it, in case the .export isn't doing so itself (which I doubt).

It turns out Crystal [relies heavily on the printer driver for Unicode support](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/a09051e9-721e-2b10-11b6-f9c65c64ef29), so I decided to look into that. Turns out the printer driver *had* to support Unicode, and this *was* the case on my test environment. While this was interesting to find out, it didn't solve my problem - I already had a compatible printer driver.

So, finally: after a few days of trying to find a solution to this, my boss decided it was time to cut our losses, and we instead planned for a re-design of the feature, without involving Crystal Report to Text exports. I am still, however, very interested in how to export to a Unicode text file with Crystal - so please do answer if you know how.

Comment: Your second link is broken. There's a redundant 'https//' in it.